# Unable to find interface javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

Tags: jpa, netbeans, persistence

I am trying to setup a new Netbeans project with JPA. The Java SDK version is 1.5.0_22-b03 and J2EE version is J2EE 1.4.I am using TOPLINK Essentials for JPA.

Going by [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface comes with J2EE 1.4.

Then why it's not able to find `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPA 1.0 specification is meant to cater to Java EE 5 containers and not J2EE 1.4 containers (unless the same also support EJB 3.0 like the erstwhile OC4J containers from Oracle). Likewise JPA 2.0 caters to Java EE 6 containers.

I would suggest using Netbeans with Java EE 5 or Java EE 6, instead of heading for a wild goose chase on getting your JPA 1.0/2.0 provider to work amicably with a J2EE 1.4 container. This isn't merely about placing some JARs in your compile time classpath; your runtime classpath will require classes that are available only in a Java EE 5/6 container.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an incorrect classpath or you are missing a required jar. What are you using to build?

Comment: Can you please elaborate "What are you using to build?".Secondly How to check classpath is correct or not?

Comment: I have included toplink essential library,what other lib could be missing?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Ant? Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You have not correctly included the j2ee-1.4.jar in your project classpath. Otherwise you can reference to it. Perhaps you meet problem in setting classpath of your java project in netbeans.

Please check your jar to ensure it is correctly downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an old question but since no other answer has been posted, I post what I was able to do to make it work.

I found a file at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.1\java\modules\ext\hibernate4

Right-click your project >Libraries >Add jar > find your Netbeans installation directory...

usually => C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeansXXX

find java\modules\ext\hibernate4 and choose jboss-transaction-apixxxxx.jar

hope it helps everyone else,